# Permissions error when uploading/writing file outside of ColdFusion webroot

Tags: apache, coldfusion, permissions

I've got a site that requires file uploads (job history/resumé). I want to upload the files to a folder outside the web root for safety reasons. On my local development machine, it works fine. But on my production server I continue to get a permissions error. What am I doing wrong?

In the upload CFC I've got it set up so that I detect the file extension, create a UUID and rename the file when writing it to the folder outside the root. This block is set up inside a try/catch block and sends the error back to the page for me to read the error in console.

Here's the JSON encoded `cfcatch.Detail` and `cfcatch.Message` error I'm getting...

> Write Exception The cause of this exception was: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/www/ftp/uploadfoldername/8915DD79-F7BD-B66E-ACE2FBFE7DBE9006.txt (Permission denied). | An error occurred when performing a file operation write on file /var/www/ftp/uploadfoldername/8915DD79-F7BD-B66E-ACE2FBFE7DBE9006.txt.

When I run getfacl on the folder  that I'm trying to upload to it looks like this:

```
# file: uploadfoldername
# owner: root
# group: apache
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:apache:rw-
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

Comment: Does your Apache user have write access to that folder?

Comment: What is coldfusion running as? nobody? Apache?

Comment: Oh, good question. It's actually running as nobody...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the CF user needs access to those folders - but obviously not as nobody. Change the user to Apache or another user with appropriate permissions to those folders.

Comment: I was hoping for a different answer only because I've got 9 other sites on this server and I think changing the user to something else is going to play heck. Regardless, your answer does indeed address my concern.

Comment: I feel your pain :)  But yeah... not much help for it I think. Bite the bullet.

Comment: I wonder what the ripple effect will be on the other sites. Should be interesting.

Comment: IF you use apache you might get away with it - since it will likely have permissions to access (not sure about write) to the site root directories.  Still - get your chmod and chuser samples out :D